# Text alignment in an actionsheet

Tags: swiftui

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showingExampleSentences) {
      ActionSheet(title: Text("Example Sentence"), message: Text(sentence_foreign_language + "\n" + .sentence_english), buttons: [.default(Text("OK"))]);
    }
```

I've got a SwiftUI action sheet where it displays two lines of text, but by default they are centre-aligned. Is there a way to make it aligned to the top-left?

Comment: sorry, alamodey! i deleted my answer.

Comment: any luck with this ?